# Type 'BaseResponse<IavailableParameters[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'IavailableParameters[]': length, pop, etc

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, api, observable

I'm doing a get call to my API and returning a list of an object. I'm then assigning that data to a property in my DataService so I can use it across components.

Here is the code in my component calling the service:

```
  getAvailableParameters() {
     this.verificationService.getAvailableParameters(this.itemNumbers).subscribe((res => {
      this.dataService.availableParameters = res;
    }))}
```

Here is the call to the API

```
  getAvailableParameters(itemNumbers: string[]){
    return this.http.get<BaseResponse<IavailableParameters[]>>(`${this.baseUrl}api/verification/${itemNumbers}`)
  }
```

Here is the property in the DataService that should store the object after getAvailableParameters is called:

```
export class DataService {
  public orderInfo: Iorder;
  public availableParameters: IavailableParameters[];
}
```

As you can see, the object coming back from the API is also wrapped in a BaseResponse object (which I believe to be the problem but don't know how to resolve), Defined here:

```
import { Error } from './Error'

export interface BaseResponse<T> {
    isSuccessful: boolean,

    error: Error;

    results: T;
}
```

This is the exact error I'm getting:

```
    ERROR in src/app/Components/verification-reply/verification-reply.component.ts(28,7): error TS2740: Type 'BaseResponse<IavailableParameters[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'IavailableParameters[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.
```

When I remove the base response type, it works fine, as I'm assuming it doesn't register that as an array or something. This binding method to the data service object worked fine when the object I returned was not an array.

I am inexperienced in this subject and could use some help figuring out how to resolve this error.

Comment: As Lindas comment suggested, the "results" object on the base response contained the actual object I was looking for. Instead of mapping res => IavailableParameters, I needed to grab res.results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I remove the base response type, it works fine, as I'm assuming it doesn't register that as an array or something.

That is to be expected because `BaseResponse<IavailableParameters[]>` is not an an array.  It is an `object` with properties `isSuccessful`, `error`, and `results`.  The *property* `results` is an array `IavailableParameters[]`.

You need to make sure that whatever type you are providing to `this.http.get` matches the actual type that is returned from the request.  Is it an array of `IavailableParameters`?  Or an object with `isSuccessful`, `error`, and `results`?

If you have a variable `response` of type `BaseResponse<IavailableParameters[]>` and you are trying to use it as an array `IavailableParameters[]`, like in the error message that you posted, then just use `response.results` instead of the entire response object.